# Android: Protect app folder from deletion

Tags: java, android, file

My android application creating a directory (**myDir**) and saving a .txt(**config.txt**) file inside it, this myDir and .txt will be created in phone memory when the app is running the first time. inside this .txt file I keeping some app configuration information.

I need to protect this .txt and myDir (directory) from accident deletion by users. is there any way to accomplish this.?

Thanks, Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really NO ACTUALLY, And with Marshmellow 6.0, you are no longer even allowed to create Directories OUTSIDE YOUR PROJECT ENVIRONMENT. Please try to create directories and files in your project directory, WHICH IS PRIVATE, AND CAN NEVER BE ACCESSED, Unless the phone got rooted. And that magical directory is located here

Activity.getFilesDir( Context mContext );

This returns the directory structure of our APP'S PRIVATE MEMORY. Do your Reading and Writing there :), and that comes from Android framework, and as far as this statement is concerned **I need to protect this .txt and myDir (directory) from accident deletion by users**, remember the ALL-TIME PROMPT, ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE IT??. Hitting Yes, would not be an ACCIDENT then, my lady :)